# Get Craft UserGroup by ID in Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, database, user-groups

I'm trying to get a record from my database for a UserGroup (although I'm guessing this applies to a few scenarios really - anything that isn't a Craft Element.

I'm still new to plugin development so I could be approaching this entirely wrong but I'm pretty sure I don't want to be using `craft()->db->createCommand()` because it might break in a future version of craft when the schema changes and I also can't do it by using `craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::UserGroup);` because it's not an element.

Is there a best practice for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to go through Craft's [service](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/#craft.app.services) layer to get things like that.

There is a [UserGroupsService](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/UserGroupsService), which has all sorts of handy methods for retrieving UserGroups like [getGroupById()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/UserGroupsService#getGroupById-detail) and [getGroupByHandle()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/UserGroupsService#getGroupByHandle-detail).

You can invoke these from your plugin like:

```
$userGroup = craft()->usergroups->getGroupById(3);
$groupName = $userGroup->name;
```

Note that these will return a [UserGroupModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/UserGroupModel) populated with your UserGroup information.

Comment: No problem.  Care to mark it as the answer? :)